# document upload ajax is not working for loading partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.3, prototype-rails. I am implementing document upload with paperclip and using ajax to display uploaded list like document name, and document url without refreshing page.

Error I am facing is:

```
SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `documents` (`course_id`, `created_at`, `document_content_type`, `document_file_name`, `document_file_size`, `document_upload_at`, `title`, `updated_at`) VALUES (38, '2013-12-17 12:49:21', 'application/pdf', 'coverletters.pdf', 441676, NULL, ' doc124', '2013-12-17 12:49:21')
(87.3ms)  COMMIT
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 16836ms (ActiveRecord: 89.6ms)
```

my document controller

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

def upload_document
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
@course_topics=@course.course_topics.ordered
@course_documents=@course.documents.ordered
@document=Document.new(params[:document].merge(:course_id => @course.id))
if @document.save
  # @document.change_document_name
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{
      render :update do |page|
        page<<"$('#documents_and_videos').html('#{escape_javascript render :partial =>  'courses/documents_and_videos_view'}');$('#descrip_txt').val('');
$('#fileinput').val('');$('#doc_name').html('Select word doc,pdf,ppt formats only')"
      end
    }
  end
else
  render :update do |page|
    page.reload
  end
end
end
```

document.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :document, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
Document upload:<%= f.text_field :description%>
<%= f.file_field :document, :onchange =>"getdocname(this)" %>
<%= f.submit 'Upload' %>
<%end%>
```

I cannot use gem 'remotipart' as prototype-rails i am using. any solution please?

Document Model

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :document, :course_id, :title
 has_many :discussions, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to  :course
has_attached_file :document, {:styles => {:large => "640*480",  :medium => "300*300>",  :thumb => "100*100>" }}

validates :title,:presence =>true

has_attached_file :document, {:styles => {:large => "640*480",  :medium => "300*300>",  :thumb => "100*100>" }}
```

upload_document.js.erb

```
$("#documents_and_videos").html('<%= escape_javascript render :partial =>"/courses/documents_and_videos_view" %>');
```

_documents_and_videos_view.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to course_document.title, course_document_path(:account_id=>current_user.account_id,:course_id =>@course,:id =>course_document),:target =>"_blank?"%></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "View",course_document_path(:account_id=>current_user.account_id,:course_id=>@course,:id =>course_document),:class =>"view_btn",:target =>"_blank?" %>
    </td>
    <td><%= course_document.present? ? 'Doc' : ''%></td>
    <td><%= link_to "D(#{course_document.discussions.count})",course_document_path(:account_id=>current_user.account_id,:course_id =>@course,:id =>course_document),:target =>"_blank?"%></td>
```

Comment: data in `Document model` ?

Comment: Uploading documents with AJAX doesn't work. You need to use iframe, see gem "remotipart" but it's using jQuery.

Comment: i am searching alternate solution of remotipart which i cannot use with prototype @IgorKasyanchuk

Comment: @Nithin: Please view updated portion

Comment: you can use jquery in parallel with prototype. With jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: so if i use remotipart gem will it work?

Comment: jQuery and $ both is working fine so no need to use JQuery.noConflict(). I tried also not solved.

Comment: @user2606967 try commenting `{:style =>...`

Comment: please try to understand problem first, Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 16836ms (ActiveRecord: 89.6ms) is telling record is successfully saved to database. Only it is not viewing without refreshing the page. Problem with ajax.